# put a plot inside a table

Tags: tables, pgfplots, plot

i want to :) well as you can see

[image]

```
    \documentclass[french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multirow,array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath} %add mathematic symbols
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pagebreak
\center{\large{\hspace{2 cm}Résultats}}\\
~\\
%{*{2}{m{0.48\textwidth}}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multirow{5}{*}{\raisebox{-\totalheight}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group name=my plots,group size= 2 by 3,horizontal sep =1.5cm,vertical sep =2cm},height=6.5cm,width=8cm]
       \nextgroupplot[legend pos=north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        %scaled ticks=false, %enlever le.10^-5 !!!!!!!!!!!!*
        %ylabeltickpos= left,       
        %yticklabel pos=left,
        y tick label style={anchor=east},       
        %xtick=data,    
        %xticklabel={0,20,40,60,80,100,120},        
        xticklabel=\empty,
        ytick pos=left,
        scaled ticks=true,      
        xmin=0,
        xmax=110,
        xlabel=Temps,
        ylabel=Absorbance,      
title=CuSm/graphite,        
        ]
                %\addlegendimage{empty legend};
                \addplot[red, mark=+] table{Annexes/resultats/BET/GRAPbjh1.dat};\label{plotsplot1}
               %\addplot[green, mark=o] table{Annexes/resultats/BET/GRAPbjh2.dat};\label{plotsplot2}
                %\addlegendentry{Graphite}[15 pt];               
              % \addplot[green] table{Annexes/resultats/BET/GRAP1.dat};  
                %\coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);% coordinate at top of the firs
        \end{groupplot}
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      %\node[text width=6cm,align=center,anchor=north] at ([yshift=-2mm]my plots c1r1.south) {\captionof{subfigure}{ \label{subplot:one}}};      
 \end{tikzpicture}}}
& Date: & {05/05/2015}\\
\cline{2-3}
 & Conditions & \\
\cline{2-3}
 & Agitation: & Oui \\
 & M$_{Métribuzine}$: & \SI{10}{\milli\gram}\\
 & M$_{Catalyseur}$: & \SI{200}{\milli\gram}\\
\hline
oui & non & oui\\ 
 \end{tabular}
%\end{figure}
%\ref{subplot:one}
%\ref{named}
%\restoregeometry  
\end{document}
```

Comment: that is certainly not a _minimal_ example ;)

Comment: it works for me -___- thanks for participating

Comment: I emphasized the word minimal ;)

Comment: i added a smiley -___-

Comment: @Hamza.w: I would take a look at this, but at the moment I can't compile your code because it needs a lot of packages that I don't have installed on my system (and which probably have nothing to do with the problem). Could you remove all the code that's not necessary to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: done did some changes

Comment: @Hamza.w: It still has a lot of unnecessary packages (`memoir`, `babel`, `siunitx`, ...), and we don't have your data file so we can't compile this document. Please try to make your code as simple as possible while still reproducing the error, and make it self-contained. I know that's annoying, but it's also annoying for those trying to help who would have to do it as well.

Comment: @Jake If you comment out `\addplot` the document still compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to husk an MWE and construct a suggestion how to solve your problem:

```
    \documentclass[french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,minimum width=80mm, minimum height=65mm] {instead of diagram};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    & 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
    Date:   & {05/05/2015}      \\
        \hline
    Conditions          &       \\
        \hline
    Agitation:          & Oui   \\
    M\textsubscript{Métribuzine}:  & \SI{10}{\milli\gram}\\
    M\textsubscript{Catalyseur}:   & \SI{200}{\milli\gram}\\
        \hline
\end{tabular}\\
oui & non \qquad\qquad oui
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With it I obtain the following figure/table:

[image]

Is this what you looking for? I omit horizontal lines. They presence is matter of taste. If you like to have them, just add `\hline` on the begin and end of content of the first tabular environment.